# How to determine pressed modifier keys when a Cocoa app is started?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsevent

In an app I'm developing, a database is used to store all user data, usually located somewhere in Library/Application Support. In order to enable the user to switch the database, I want to implement a functionality similar to iTunes or iPhoto, where the app asks for the library's or database's location if the option key is pressed upon starting the app.

How can I check the currently pressed (modifier) keys if no NSEvent is at hand?

I already tried:

**`[NSResponder flagsChanged:(NSEvent *)theEvent]`** – Probably not called because the option key is already down before the window and any responders are instantiated.

**`[[NSApplication sharedApplication] currentEvent]`** – Returns `nil`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put this in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`:

```
NSUInteger modifiers = ([NSEvent modifierFlags] & NSDeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask);

if (modifiers == NSAlternateKeyMask)   { 
    // do your stuff here 
}
```

Beginning with macOS 10.12, this should be:

```
NSUInteger modifiers = ([NSEvent modifierFlags] & NSEventModifierFlagDeviceIndependentFlagsMask);

if (modifiers == NSEventModifierFlagOption)   { 
    // do your stuff here 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5 variant:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunch(_ aNotification: Notification?) {

    if NSEvent.modifierFlags.intersection(.deviceIndependentFlagsMask) == .option {
        // Your code
    }

}
```